# PHP CURL Ping function failing with existing host

Tags: php, curl

This is my PHP CURL function for pinging hosts:

```
function ping_url($host)
{

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(!$httpResponse or empty($httpResponse)) {
return false;   
}

return true;

}
```

It works for the majority of domains. However, today I tried the following:

```
if (!ping_url('zapper.com')) {
echo 'false';   
} else {
echo 'true';    
}
```

and it keeps failing.

Any ideas why this could be happening? The website [zapper.com](http://zapper.com) exists.

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure your empty() test is necessary? if it isn't, try removing it and see how it goes

Comment: @Enjoyted - just tried, same result. Thanks though!

Comment: @Federico - do you think that's the reason? How can I specify this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Hope it can help you.